# Error in loop, only one value is added to Data Frame with results in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, loops

I have loop like below, and by doing so I need to calculate prediction for store = 1 and store = 85, but nevermind... real problem is, why in results data frame: "df_all_2" I have results only for store 1, so my loop works bad, because I need results for store 85 and 1, but I do not see error in this loop, can you help me ?

```
sample_df = data.query('Store in [85, 1]')
Store_list = sample_df["Store"].unique().tolist()

df_result = pd.DataFrame(columns=["Date", "Store", "Sales", "Sales_Prediction"])
df_result.set_index("Date", inplace=True)

for store in Store_list:
    sample_df = data_XGB[data_XGB["Store"]==store]

    train_set = sample_df[:'2014-07-02']
    test_set = sample_df["2014-07-03":]

    X_train_XGB = train_set.loc[:, train_set.columns != "Sales"]
    y_train_XGB = train_set.loc[:, train_set.columns == "Sales"]

    X_test_XGB = test_set.loc[:, test_set.columns != "Sales"]
    y_test_XGB = test_set.loc[:, test_set.columns == "Sales"]
    
    reg = xgb.XGBRegressor(n_estimators=1000)
    reg.fit(X_train_XGB, y_train_XGB,
            eval_set=[(X_train_XGB, y_train_XGB), (X_test_XGB, y_test_XGB)],
            early_stopping_rounds=50,
            verbose=False) 
    
    test_set['Sales_Prediction'] = reg.predict(X_test_XGB)
    train_set['Sales_Prediction'] = reg.predict(X_train_XGB)
    
    df_all = pd.concat([test_set, train_set], sort=True)
    df_all = df_all[["Store", "Sales", "Sales_Prediction"]]
    df_all.reset_index(inplace=True)
    df_all["Date"] = df_all["Date"].astype("datetime64")
    df_all.sort_values(by="Date", inplace=True)
    df_all.set_index("Date", inplace=True)
    
df_all_2 = pd.concat([df_result, df_all], sort=False)
```

[image]

```
sample_df = data.query('Store in [85, 1]')
Store_list = sample_df["Store"].unique().tolist()

df_result = pd.DataFrame(columns=["Date", "Store", "Sales", "Sales_Prediction"])
df_result.set_index("Date", inplace=True)

df_prev = pd.DataFrame()

for store in Store_list:
    sample_df = data_XGB[data_XGB["Store"]==store]

    train_set = sample_df[:'2014-07-02']
    test_set = sample_df["2014-07-03":]

    X_train_XGB = train_set.loc[:, train_set.columns != "Sales"]
    y_train_XGB = train_set.loc[:, train_set.columns == "Sales"]

    X_test_XGB = test_set.loc[:, test_set.columns != "Sales"]
    y_test_XGB = test_set.loc[:, test_set.columns == "Sales"]
    
    reg = xgb.XGBRegressor(n_estimators=1000)
    reg.fit(X_train_XGB, y_train_XGB,
            eval_set=[(X_train_XGB, y_train_XGB), (X_test_XGB, y_test_XGB)],
            early_stopping_rounds=50,
            verbose=False) 
    
    test_set['Sales_Prediction'] = reg.predict(X_test_XGB)
    train_set['Sales_Prediction'] = reg.predict(X_train_XGB)
    
    df_all = pd.concat([df_prev, test_set, train_set], sort=True)
    df_all = df_all[["Store", "Sales", "Sales_Prediction"]]
    df_all.reset_index(inplace=True)
    df_all["Date"] = df_all["Date"].astype("datetime64")
    df_all.sort_values(by="Date", inplace=True)
    df_all.set_index("Date", inplace=True)
    
df_all_2 = pd.concat([df_result, df_all], sort=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

The below line will overwrite df_all the second iteration of the loop:

```
df_all = pd.concat([test_set, train_set], sort=True)
```

You should do something like:

```
df_prev = pd.DataFrame()
...
for store in Store_list:
    ...
    df_all = pd.concat([df_prev, test_set, train_set], sort=True)
```

Comment: what is df_prev ? I do not have this variable

Comment: you should initialize it before the for loop

Comment: I edited code based on your advice but it still does not work :/ COuld you give full code with your proposition ?

Comment: When asking a question try adding sample input data which in a way that can be easily reproduced by another person, without that is difficult to give working code. Also I suggest simplifying the problem to just concatenating data frames in a loop.